# How to turn vue.js method inside a component to a created method

Tags: vue.js

I am working with a vue.js code base where a method inside the component is being called by onclick()

instead I want the method to just be ran when the page loads rather than be called by onclick.  Reading the vue.js docs I believe I need to use a vue method called created(),  Can I simply replace 'method' with 'created' or what exactly do I need to do to run this method on page load.

```
<script>
    Vue.component('job-execs', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['job'],
        data: function() {
                return {
                    showExecs: false,
                    build_ids: []
                }
            },
        methods: {
            jobExecs() {
                url = "api/v2/exec?" + this.job.api_url + "&limit=10"
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(body => {
                        for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                            start_date = JSON.stringify(body[i].time_start)
                            start_date = start_date.match(/"?(.*)T(.*)/)[1];
                            this.build_ids.push({
                                'id': JSON.stringify(body[i].id),
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch( err => {
                        console.log('Error Fetching:', url, err);
                        return { 'failure': url, 'reason': err };
                    });
                }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the lifecycle of vuejs app, to first thing vuejs do is to run the `created`,

so in your case, you should put the `jobExecs` function within `created` hook.

for more information check [Instance Lifecycle Hooks Vuejs doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

in that case, your component will be like below :

```
<script>
    Vue.component('job-execs', {
        delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
        props: ['job'],
        data: function() {
                return {
                    showExecs: false,
                    build_ids: []
                }
            },
        created() {
               this.jobExecs();
        },
        methods: {
            jobExecs() {
                url = "api/v2/exec?" + this.job.api_url + "&limit=10"
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(body => {
                        for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                            start_date = JSON.stringify(body[i].time_start)
                            start_date = start_date.match(/"?(.*)T(.*)/)[1];
                            this.build_ids.push({
                                'id': JSON.stringify(body[i].id),
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch( err => {
                        console.log('Error Fetching:', url, err);
                        return { 'failure': url, 'reason': err };
                    });
                }
        },
```

Comment: I'd suggest leaving `jobExecs` as a method and invoking it from within a lifecycle hook.

Comment: How do I invoke from lifecycle hook - example?

Comment: @david Simply call `this.jobExecs()` from within the `created` or `mounted` hook for example.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim yeap you are right,  i'm going to edit my aswer